# Change Site tile/card colours

Tags: sharepoint-online, site

Is there any way to change the colour of the bar at the top of a site card/tile on the **Frequent sites** section of Sharepoint? See below for the cards I'm referring to:

[image: Example]

Comment: did you try with css?

Comment: This is on the SharePoint home page in O365 right? Then, no there is no way to change it